# review papers on P-values, adjusted P-values and common statistical tests in bioinformatics

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, references, biostatistics, bioinformatics

I'm looking for review papers which give comprehensive reviews of P-values, adjusted P-values and common statistical tests in bioinformatics.

Comment: Can you elaborate further? Are you looking for pitfalls of p-values in the context of bioinformatics?

Comment: exactly and what to do in these cases .